# Geo IP based store view selection with Varnish

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, varnish, turpentine, geoip

I have a Magento site with two store views where the store is determined by geo IP (as long as no store cookie is explicitly set). This is done by setting the environment variable `MAGE_RUN_CODE` in `index.php` before the Magento application gets initialized:

```
/* Store redirect based on geo IP, only if store cookie is not set */
if (!isset($_COOKIE['store'])) {
    $cookieExpire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;

    $storeCodes = array();
    foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $_store) {
        $storeCodes[] = $_store->getCode();
    }

    $geoip = new Sandfox_GeoIP_Model_Country;
    $geoipCountryCode = $geoip->getCountry();
    $geoipCountryCode = strtolower($geoipCountryCode);

    if (in_array($geoipCountryCode, $storeCodes)) {
        setcookie('store', $geoipCountryCode, $cookieExpire, '/');
        $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = $geoipCountryCode;
    }
}
```

This works well until I enable Varnish (using the [Turpentine extension](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/)).

- users will receive the page from cache on first visit
- the content of the cache is determined by the IP of the first visitor for each page

I can imagine a solution with a custom VCL, but unfortunately I cannot change it and have to use the default one from Turpentine.

So what I need is a way to bypass Varnish for every new visitor, determine their store view based on the IP and then serve the cached page for this store view.

Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of Geo IP detection and redirect method do you use?

Comment: @Pawel Until now, no redirection, I'm just setting the store code in `index.php`. IP detection comes from https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Sandfox_GeoIP

Comment: I added the source code, in case it's relevant.

Comment: In my opinion it's very hard  without changing the VCL. I don't know turpentine very well, but there is a placeholder where you can set your custom VCL without modifying the default VCL. Is there a way in you project to set this custom VCL?

Comment: Doesn't varnish use sessions instead of cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have probably only few options:

1. use geoip mod and custom varnish config to pass proper geoip
   hash    to backend.
2. use "VCL Fix = on" in Turpentine settings, it will    bypass request if no cookies or magento session. (caution: high load)
3. set all geoip cookies and variables with javascript on client side.

better to use option 1.

but in different projects we use option 1+3

ps.
varnish 3 version this way to add hash for geoip, per country:

```
import geoip;
     sub vcl_recv {
         set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
         set req.http.X-Client-GeoIP = geoip.country_code(req.http.X-Forwarded-For);
    }

sub vcl_hash {
...
hash_data(req.http.X-Client-GeoIP);
...
}
```

actually just found this blog post which explains it better:
http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2013/10/25/geoip-with-varnish/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it was helpful! I ended up using an AJAX request that sets the store cookie based on location, if no store cookie has been set yet (so basically option 3). It works well enough for my case within my limitations.