# How to make observer Cacheable false

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, varnish

I created my module for GeoIP where I get location based on IP and set currency and stores according to It.

I have implemented the login in the first possible observer `controller_action_predispatch` to initiate this logic.

```
$currentIp = $this->_remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
$currency = $this->getCurrency($currentIp);
$this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
```

The above implementation is just an sample of what I am doing and it works great.

However when **implementing varnish** in my server my logic fails. Now My question is I dint find any solution to make **observer cacheable false** as cacheable false works for blocks I guess. Even though I may get a solution to make it cacheable false will varnish implantation be logical as my observer will be called every time and I will get my page as miss.

What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: Are you using cookie?

Comment: @padhiyar gaurang Yes

Comment: ohh!!! sometimes varnish is to unpredetable with cookie. It is due that or see my answer below. It may can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refere to this

http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2013/10/25/geoip-with-varnish/

[Geo IP based store view selection with Varnish](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139621/geo-ip-based-store-view-selection-with-varnish?rq=1)